# Create multidimensional array from single array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following sql resultset after querying a mysql table.So it's producing an array having each row as single element.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quid] => 9


        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quid] => 10


        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quid] => 11


        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quid] => 9


        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quid] => 10


        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quid] => 11


        )



)
```

Now I would like to create another array using php where the first key will hold all the entire array resultset and so on.

```
Array
    (
     [0] => array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [quid] => 9

            )

            [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [quid] => 10

            )

           [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [quid] => 11

            )
    )
    [1] => array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [quid] => 9

            )

            [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [quid] => 10

            )

           [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [quid] => 11

            )
    )
)
```

Comment: `$newArray = array($originalArray);`

Comment: Sorry I should have told more.I want it to be incremental.

Comment: Then please edit your question to show what you actually want: what should be incremental? perhaps [array_chunk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) is what you're looking for, but that's just a guess until you clarify what you need

Comment: Sorry guys once again.I have edited the question.

Comment: Just wondering if it is better to modify the sql instead creating inside the resultset. The quid can be single or duplicates and will be always.

Comment: `$newArray = array_chunk($originalArray, 3);`

Comment: Your question is unclear as to the criteria for aggregating items into the second nesting level. How do you determine this? Is it always three items per each top level array, or is there something in the values of ther records themselves that determines nesting behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I'll happily edit/update this answer as further details are provided.

If I may, I think your issue is further "upstream" than your PHP code.  I'd suggest something in your database schema is missing...

As best I can tell - (your question needs more detail to be honest) - you've got two dimensional information in your database:

```
[x,y]
```

So we could see this as:

```
[0, 9],[0,10],[0,11]
[1, 9],[1,10],[1,11]
```

If in your schema you have two columns - `x,y` - you only need select both and parse appropriately in PHP:

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$res = do_query("SELECT x,y FROM tbl;");
while ($row = get_row($res))
   $arr[$row['x']] = $row['y'];
```

etc.

If you don't have both columns in your database, I'm completely unclear as to how you're going to procedurally break 1-dimensional information into 2.

Perhaps you could demonstrate your schema and some sample data, and provide a fuller explanation of the problem you're trying to solve?